# Why can't I build an Angular app that references an internal Angular library?

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli, node-modules

**tl;dr;** `ng build` removes /dist folder containing my compiled custom library. That invalidates all references to that library in my project's code, which causes `ng build` to ultimately fail. What am I doing wrong?

I've followed [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries) and [guides](https://medium.com/better-programming/angular-7-series-part-2-create-custom-library-8d7a0494b2cc) to generate a library with the Angular CLI within an existing project. I ran `ng build @mylib` and then `npm install dist/@mylib`. A module or two in my app imports components from @mylib as they would from any npm installed module (`import { MyLibComponent } from '@mylib';`) These references, however, break as soon as I build the app, because `ng build` deletes the /dist folder, which contains the compiled @mylib.

You'd think the /node_modules would contain the compiled files, but it actually just uses a virtual link to the problematic /dist folder.

Comment: why not move the `/dist` folder before running `npm install` on it?

Comment: @Woohoojin That seems like a lot to ask another dev to do upon a fresh install of the app, no?

Comment: haha what? `ng build -op another_folder/`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output path of your library should be in a separate folder in the `dist` folder than your application output.

I created an example for this, you can find it in following repo:
https://github.com/tenkmilan/angular-workspace-example

In the above case in `angular.json` the application output is `"outputPath": "dist/my-app"` and the library output in `ng-package.json` is `"dest": "../../dist/my-lib"`. To have the sources of your library output included in your application following configuration is needed in the root `tsconfig.json` of the workspace:

```
"paths": {
  "my-lib": [
    "dist/my-lib"
  ],
  "my-lib/*": [
    "dist/my-lib/*"
  ]
}
```

This way the library output won't be deleted and it will be included in your application directly.

Comment: This is kinda what I was thinking might be necessary. I would have just thought that the CLI would have been smart enough to do something like this on its own. It automatically makes a project folder in your project when you have it generate a library. It also adds the related configuration to the angular.json file. That's why it's surprising that it would put the output of a library build in a place that the build process for the app would delete it

Comment: The folder structure of your application revealed my issue. Since I added the library to an existing app, my structure featured the app code outside the projects folder, with just the lib code in that folder. That's the reason `ng build` on the app deleted the whole /dist folder and wiped out the lib's output files.